# Windows 8.1 app How to access control within BottomAppBar flyout?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

x:Name does not work on user controls that are within a flyout that is a child element of a page's BottomAppBar.  I'm trying to access this custom userControl from the code behind.  Any ideas how this can be done?

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar IsOpen="{Binding AppBarOpen,
                             Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsSticky="{Binding AppBarSticky,
                               Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Grid>
<!--Other controls and whatnot here including column specifications and leftpanel stuff-->
<VariableSizedWrapGrid x:Name="appbarrightPanel"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                   Orientation="Horizontal">
<AppBarButton x:Name="appbarbtnUpload"
                              Click="appbarbtnUpload_Click"                                 
                              Label="Upload">
                    <AppBarButton.Icon>
                        <BitmapIcon Width="22"
                                    Height="22"
                                    UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/TopAppbarIcons/icon_upload.png" />
                    </AppBarButton.Icon>
<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <Flyout>
                            <usercontrols:UploadControl x:Name="uploadControl"  ParentPage="Tag List Page" FileChoosen="UploadControl_FileChoosen" Margin="-20"/>
                        </Flyout>
                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                </AppBarButton>
            </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Again, doing uploadControl.blah does not work because I cannot even access uploadControl.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to directly connect to it via it's name BUT I was able to hook into it's Loaded and Unloaded events to access it.  You can probably get the object itself by casting the sender object.  Just being able to access the object in the onLoad was good enough for my purposes.